# Why does Prawn resize my image automatically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, prawn

When I try to insert an image (PNG at 72dpi) using Prawn, like this:

```
image "#{Rails.root}/public/images/pdf/logo.png"
```

Prawn inserts the image but scales it up by about 30% which makes it blurry (and bigger.) I dont have anything else in the file and the PDF initialization is fairly standard:

```
super(:page_layout => :portrait,
      :left_margin => 0.5.in,
      :right_margin => 0.5.in,
      :top_margin => 1.in,
      :bottom_margin => 0.5.in)
```

Based on the documentation, Prawn is supposed to insert the picture into the document without any modifications whatsoever.  Why is this image resizing happening?

---

NOTE: 
I noticed that bounding boxes are also bigger than they should be (by the same ratio as my image).

Comment: This issue might have something to do with how PDF files act more like a print version than a screen version of a document.  Unless changing the `dpi` does anything (which, according to [this old thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/prawn-ruby/MbMsCx862iY) doesn't seem to have an effect,) you could try setting the `:width` and `:height` parameters when inserting the image; I tried that on a test file, and it does sharpen up the image, a bit.

Comment: Also, for reference: "The base unit in Prawn is the PDF Point. One PDF Point is equal to 1/72 of an inch."

Comment: Yes, I did try to set image size and I my picture is at 72dpi. So far my solution is to use an image 2x bigger than needed and scale it down to 20%. The picture still looks blurry on screen but it is "perfect" when printed.

Comment: Glad to hear you have a method for doing that; also, the blurriness on the screen (for the PDF) might be related to automatic anti-aliasing effects in your PDF reader.  If there is a way to turn off the anti-aliasing in the PDF reader settings, your image should look a little sharper... :)

Comment: Nah, if it was just the AA effect, it would not grow the picture by about 25%. This is odd.

Comment: Yeah, for the resizing part; I just meant for PDF (raster) image blurriness in general...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can try passing the width and height that the image actually is see if that helps

**Prawn::Images**

> Public Instance Methods
>    image(file, options={}) click to toggle source

Add the image at filename to the current page. Currently only JPG and PNG files are supported.

> NOTE: Prawn is very slow at rendering PNGs with alpha channels. The
>   workaround for those who don’t mind installing RMagick is to use:

[github.com/amberbit/prawn-fast-png](http://github.com/amberbit/prawn-fast-png)

Arguments:

file path to file or an object that responds to #

Options:

**:at** an array [x,y] with the location of the top left corner of the image.

**:position** One of (:left, :center, :right) or an x-offset

**:vposition** One of (:top, :center, :center) or an y-offset

**:height** the height of the image [actual height of the image]

**:width** the width of the image [actual width of the image]

**:scale** scale the dimensions of the image proportionally

**:fit** scale the dimensions of the image proportionally to fit inside [width,height]

```
Prawn::Document.generate("image2.pdf", :page_layout => :landscape) do     
    pigs = "#{Prawn::BASEDIR}/data/images/pigs.jpg" 
    image pigs, :at => [50,450], :width => 450                                      

    dice = "#{Prawn::BASEDIR}/data/images/dice.png"
    image dice, :at => [50, 450], :scale => 0.75 
  end
```

If only one of :width / :height are provided, the image will be scaled proportionally. When both are provided, the image will be stretched to fit the dimensions without maintaining the aspect ratio.

If :at is provided, the image will be place in the current page but the text position will not be changed.

If instead of an explicit filename, an object with a read method is passed as file, you can embed images from IO objects and things that act like them (including Tempfiles and open-uri objects).

```
  require "open-uri"

  Prawn::Document.generate("remote_images.pdf") do 
    image open("http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/media/prawn_logo.png")
  end
```

This method returns an image info object which can be used to check the dimensions of an image object if needed. (See also: Prawn::Images::PNG , Prawn::Images::JPG)

Comment: Hi,i would like to know if I want to position the image at the center of the pdf what should i do?I know der is vposition n position but I have text that needs to come above the image so I cant use position n vposition